# What are the pros and cons of synchronous versus asynchronous networking?

Tags: android, ios

I am quite frustrated at the amount documentation that says explicitly you should use asynchronous code for networking.

I even read an article which outright states 'Networking is an inherently asynchronous operation.'

https://react-native.org/doc/network.html

So first there is a *difference* between background processing and asynchronous code.

For example, running code asynchronously doesn't necessarily mean it is on the background.  For this we can actually use a background thread.

When you write an iOS app, and you have several view controllers, each accessing the same data which is downloaded by the Model, when you download the data for code asynchronously, you have a frustrating tangle of callbacks and asynchronous messages being passed throughout the application.

When I have multiple view controllers using the same data this poses a problem, how do I make sure I don't have the view controller which is opened accessing the data before it is downloaded?  You might not be able to tell which controller was opened first so this poses an issue, how do you make sure they don't access the data until it is finished downloading?

I suppose you solve this using a completion handler and a model which then fires off a Key Value Observing notification calling the controller when it is finished downloading (a push model).

But what happens if the said controller is *not loaded* when the notification is posted, does this mean it never gets the data?  Wouldn't it make more sense to use a pull model, so when the controller is loaded it can check if the data is available, if so how do you handle this with an async paradigm?

But any notification callback cannot access the outlying scope of the rest of the controller.

However I have written some entirely synchronous code which uses locks and semaphores.  The model downloads the data synchronously in a *background* thread.  The controller classes (*if they are loaded*) check the Model class to see if the data is available.  Locks mean that the code cannot access the data if the data is not downloaded.  The App signals when the data has finished downloading and while all controllers and models use the same shared synchronous DispatchQueue this prevents the controllers accessing the data arrays when they are empty or the data is being downloaded.

Async code commonly produces weakly coupled code that can't access the scope of the rest of the class and you have methods firing at different times and in different places in the app which i think is difficult to keep track of.  So why is networking 'an inherently asynchronous operation'?

Can anyone provide sound scientific reasons why asynchronous code is better, or reasons why I should not do what I have done with synchronous code, and also methods of how you can make asynchronous code safer, less spaghetti like, easier to work with and easier to read?

CODE:

Table View Controller

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    if !fromSelectionCtrllr {

        let downloader = Downloader.sharedInstance
        let group = downloader.group

        group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {

            let defaults : UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let firstLaunch = defaults.bool(forKey: "firstLaunch")

            if firstLaunch {
                self.arrayOfData = Model.sharedInstance.provideData()
            } else {
                self.arrayOfData = Model.sharedInstance.provideNewData()
            }

            for object in self.arrayOfData {

                if let deviceName = object.chargeDeviceName {

                    let theSubscript = deviceName.prefix(1)

                    let theString = String(theSubscript)

                    if !self.sectionTitles.contains(theString) {

                        self.sectionTitles.append(theString)
                    }
                } else {

                    self.sectionTitles.append("")
                }

                if let deviceName = object.chargeDeviceName  {

                    let string = String(describing: deviceName.prefix(1))

                    var arry = self.chargingPointDict[string]

                    if arry == nil {

                        arry = []
                    }

                    arry?.append(object)

                    self.chargingPointDict.updateValue(arry!, forKey: string)

                } else {

                    self.chargingPointDict[" "]?.append(object)
                }
            }

            self.sectionTitles = self.removeDuplicates(array: self.sectionTitles)

            self.sectionTitles = self.sectionTitles.sorted( by: { $0 < $1 })

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })

    }

    fromSelectionCtrllr = false

}
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if (searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty)! {

        if self.sectionTitles.isEmpty {

            cell.textLabel?.text = "Nothing to display"
            return cell

        } else {

            let mySectionIndex = self.sectionTitles[indexPath.section]

            if mySectionIndex != "" {

                let arrayOfPoints : [ChargingPoint] = self.chargingPointDict[mySectionIndex]!

                let object : ChargingPoint = arrayOfPoints[indexPath.row]

                cell.textLabel?.text = object.chargeDeviceName

                return cell

            } else {

                return cell
            }

        }

    } else {

        let object : ChargingPoint = self.filteredPoints[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = object.chargeDeviceName

        return cell
    }


}
```

Model Class

```
class Model: NSObject {

var currentChargingPointArray : [ChargingPoint] = []
var newChargingPointArray : [ChargingPoint] = []

var latitude : Double?
var longitude : Double?

var annotationArray : [ChargingPointAnnotation] = []
var newAnnotationArray : [ChargingPointAnnotation] = []

static let downloader = Downloader.sharedInstance

var savedRegion : MKCoordinateRegion? = nil

/* The model class is a singleton */
static let sharedInstance : Model = {
    let instance = Model()

    return instance
}()

fileprivate override init( ) {} //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.

func setLocation(lat: Double, long: Double) {

    self.latitude = lat
    self.longitude = long
}

func returnData(array: Array<ChargingPoint>) {

    currentChargingPointArray = []

    var seen = Set<String>()
    var unique = [ChargingPoint]()
    for point in array {
        if !seen.contains(point.chargeDeviceId!) {
            unique.append(point)
            seen.insert(point.chargeDeviceId!)
        }
    }

    currentChargingPointArray = unique

}

func returnNewData(array: Array<ChargingPoint>) {

    newChargingPointArray = []

    var seen = Set<String>()
    var unique = [ChargingPoint]()
    for point in array {
        if !seen.contains(point.chargeDeviceId!) {
            unique.append(point)
            seen.insert(point.chargeDeviceId!)
        }
    }

    newChargingPointArray = unique

}

func provideData() -> [ChargingPoint] {

    return currentChargingPointArray

}

func provideNewData() -> [ChargingPoint] {

    return newChargingPointArray

}

func makeAnnotations() -> [ChargingPointAnnotation] {

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.jackspacie.ChargeFinder", qos: .background, attributes: [])

    queue.sync {

        self.annotationArray = []

        for chargingPoint in currentChargingPointArray {

            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: chargingPoint.latitude!, longitude: chargingPoint.longitude!)

            let annotation = ChargingPointAnnotation(location: location)
            annotation?.title = chargingPoint.chargeDeviceName
            annotation?.pointTitle = chargingPoint.chargeDeviceName

            annotation?.chargingPoint = chargingPoint

            self.annotationArray.append(annotation!)
        }

    }

    return self.annotationArray
}

func makeNewAnnotations() -> [ChargingPointAnnotation] {

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.jackspacie.ChargeFinder", qos: .background, attributes: [])

    queue.sync {

        self.newAnnotationArray = []

        for chargingPoint in newChargingPointArray {

            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: chargingPoint.latitude!, longitude: chargingPoint.longitude!)

            let annotation = ChargingPointAnnotation(location: location)
            annotation?.title = chargingPoint.chargeDeviceName
            annotation?.pointTitle = chargingPoint.chargeDeviceName

            annotation?.chargingPoint = chargingPoint

            self.newAnnotationArray.append(annotation!)
        }



    }

    return self.newAnnotationArray
}
```

Downloader Class

```
var group = DispatchGroup()
var model = Model.sharedInstance

/* The downloader class is a singleton */
static let sharedInstance : Downloader = {
    let instance = Downloader()

    return instance
}()

fileprivate override init() {} //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.


func download(lat: Double, long: Double, dist: Int)  {

    func recursive(lat: Double, long: Double, dist: Int) {

        var chargeDeviceArray : [ChargingPoint] = []

        let url = URL(string: “https://www.blah.com/lat/\(lat)/long/\(long)/dist/\(dist)/")!

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("urlSession Error")

                recursive(lat: lat, long: long, dist: dist)

                return
            } else {

                guard let unwrappedData = data else { return }
                do {
                    let jsonDict : [String: Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [] ) as! [String : Any]

                    let arrayOfDicts = jsonDict["ChargeDevice"] as? [[String: Any]]

                    for value in arrayOfDicts! {

                        let chargePoint = ChargingPoint()

                        // process data into objects.


                        chargeDeviceArray.append(chargePoint)


                    }

                    var seen = Set<String>()
                    var unique = [ChargingPoint]()
                    for point in chargeDeviceArray {
                        if !seen.contains(point.chargeDeviceId!) {
                            unique.append(point)
                            seen.insert(point.chargeDeviceId!)
                        }
                    }



                    if self.model.currentChargingPointArray.isEmpty {

                        self.model.returnData(array: unique)

                    } else {

                        self.model.returnNewData(array: unique)
                    }



                } catch {

                    print("json error: \(error)")
                }

                semaphore.signal()
            }

            //print(response) 

        }
        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    }

    self.group.enter()

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myapp.charge”, qos: .background, attributes: [])

    queue.sync {


        recursive(lat: lat, long: long, dist: dist)

    }

    self.group.leave()

}
```

Comment: I find this question oddly confusing. Are you asking us why async is used or do you have problems with how to use it in iOS? Please edit your text so that it's complete for the question you are trying to ask, but remove all non-relevant text.

Comment: I am asking both.  I dont feel that any of the text is non-relevant.  I thought about my question carefully before posting.

Comment: I feel like the question doesn’t even relate in any way to sync/async code. What you explain can be done with either. And adding a background thread to handle the loading on iOS sounds weird since there’s ways to load in the background without blocking and as far as I know that’s the recommended way. And it’s still async even if you handle it yourself and don’t use any specific keyword in the language. I would also suggest cutting the question to its essence so it can be understood and be objective. “Obsession” also makes it very non-objective

Comment: How does it not relate to sync/async code?  Yes that it essentially a good answer to the question, you can do it either way.  But in that case why have I never seen anybody writing articles on the internet touting the benefits of doing it the synchronous way?  Or explaining how to do it?  Why did facebook state 'networking is inherently an asynchronous operation?  I am looking for pros and cons of doing it both ways, and practical solutions to doing it asynchronously as well.  I still do not feel that any of the text in my question is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes "obsession" makes it sound subjective, I should have thought more carefully about the title, perhaps I should rename that.

Comment: Edited for clarity, removed non-relevant text

Comment: Ok you didn’t brutalise my question, so thanks for that!

Comment: More of a theory question than a normal SO question would be my guess

Comment: @BJHStudios Yeah I totally agree but I wasn’t sure if I should post here or another stack site like software engineers, but I am looking for practical programming responses so, posting here makes sense I guess

Comment: @BJHStudios however I find overall application design a very pertinent subject when I am coding, and would like to know I am using the best methods

Comment: I’m frustrated I haven’t received a conclusive answer on this. It seems the idea that ‘networking is inherently an asynchronous operation’ is a commonly held myth that is pervasive all over the internet, even by Facebook!! Of all companies. I would like to see some objective discussion which lays out the pros and cons of both async and sync networking in a scientific way, and I just can’t seem to find it anywhere.  As this effects my decision on how to build every app I am going to be constructing in future, this makes progress difficult.

Answer (score 0):

In short, when it comes to synchronous networking there are very limited cases where you would prefer this. Why?

Because 'A synchronous request blocks the client until operation completes' and in general you don't want the client to freeze. The user can't do anything at that time since we are waiting for all the synchronous actions to complete before enabling the client.

When using asynchronous requests you can build UI, show spinners and depending on whether you already cached older data or have other functionalities, still let the user use your client.

Comment: None of my synchronous code blocks the GUI.  The model is running a background thread and this is completely fine for it to be synchronous.  The controller classes can do what they want while this is happening.  Yes this is the argument I have heard all over the internet, and it is simply not true.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please add your so called synchronous code then, because I think you don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 0):

> When I have multiple view controllers using the same data this poses a problem, how do I make sure I don't have the view controller which
>   is opened accessing the data before it is downloaded? You might not be
>   able to tell which controller was opened first so this poses an issue,
>   how do you make sure they don't access the data until it is finished
>   downloading?
>
> I suppose you solve this using a completion handler and a model which
>   then fires off a Key Value Observing notification calling the
>   controller when it is finished downloading (a push model).
>
> But I ask this, what happens if the said controller is not loaded when
>   the notification is posted, does this mean it never gets the data?
>   Wouldn't it make more sense to use a pull model, so when the
>   controller is loaded it can check if the dat is available, if so how
>   do you handle this with an async paradigm?

Load UI-> Show Progress Dialog -> Perform ASYNC(LoadData,SetData intoController)-> DismissDialog

Idk if  this is what you're refering

I really dont see an oportunity where you will prefer block UI Thread and freeze App until it loads the data synchronically

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I really don't feel you have provided enough information, or even argued how exactly this solves the issue of controllers not being ready to receive a notification, or how this removes code spaghetti, or solves the issue of async tasks firing at different times and not having context from their parent classes.

Comment: If you do code spaghetti its because youre not following a design pattern

Comment: Thank you, what design pattern should I follow?

Comment: I Will edit mi aswer when I get home just leaving work :p

Answer (score 0):

The article states that "networking is an inherently asynchronous operation" because networking *is* an inherently asynchronous operation.

Synchronous means "happening at the same time".  Specifically in computing it means with reference to a specific time period or clock signal. For example, electrically, the CPU operates  synchronously, which is why we talk about the clock speed of a computer.

Synchronous *does not mean "blocking"* although that is a common (mis)interpretation.  In fact, Apple hasn't helped here with their function names. Technically they should be something like `DispatchQueue.nonBlockingOperation()` and `DispatchQueue.blockingOperation()` rather than `async`/`sync`.

Synchronous systems can operate at much higher speeds but require a very controlled environment, which is why you find synchronous operation at the core of a computer but not so much outside it.

Your code blocks a background queue waiting for the download to complete, but the download still completes *asynchronously*.  If it were completing *synchronously* you wouldn't need the semaphore.  You would know that the data would be available at the specified point in time (say 0.2 seconds from now or whatever).

Your `Downloader` class also still notifies the view controller about the available data asynchronously via the dispatch group `notify`.

From what I can see, you have added a bunch of complexity to the solution (By adding a dispatch group and a semaphore) and introduced the potential for deadlocks but *you still have asynchronous code*. You block the background queue waiting for the completion of the download, but you still notify the data consumers asynchronously.

The same outcome could be achieved using the standard delegation or completion handler patterns with much less complexity. If there are potentially multiple parties interested in knowing about the new data then you can use the `NotificationCentre` to "broadcast" that information.

By the way, loosely coupled code is generally considered more desirable.

Comment: Thanks, that’s basically what I wanted to hear.  Can you direct me to any reading material that will clarify this situation for me?

Comment: Can you tell me how I have potential for deadlocks? And how I’ve introduced complexity?  What is the superfluous code I should remove?  Still this does prevent the view controllers that load later than a KVO notification from missing it, how can that be resolved with a standard pattern?

Comment: Unless you are dealing with real-time systems in embdedded computing synchronous doesn't typically apply above the electrical signal level. [refer here](https://www.computerscience.gcse.guru/theory/synchronous-and-asynchronous). At the software level think about the old war movies where they say "let's synchronise our watches"; they are going to blow up the bridge or whatever with reference to a specific point in time, so they need that common reference. Asynchronous might be "when you hear the bridge blow, fire the red flare"

Comment: Wow, that is NOT what I understood it to mean, thanks

Comment: Well, the code specified in the dispatch notify could have passed as a completion handler.  You could invoke the passed completion handler from the dataTask completion handler.  This has the same result with no semaphore, no dispatch group. You have the potential for a deadlock because you have a shared object, no preemption and "hold and wait". These are the conditions required for a potential deadlock.

Comment: Yes, you are conflating (as is common) synchronous/asynchronous with blocking/non-blocking. Non-blocking code is typically used to deal with asynchronous events.  Modern UI driven code, like apps, are almost completely driven by asynchronous events; you don't know when the user is going to tap or scroll or whatever, you just react. You extend that same paradigm to dealing with the network; you don't know when the network operation will complete, nor the outcome (it could succeed or fail), you just react when it does.

Comment: the thing here is that the app will not function without the data so if the network operation is blocking because it’s not downloading that is basically irrelevant.  I’m pretty sure I’m not confusing synchronous/asynchronous with blocking/non blocking; I know the difference.  I find the whole running asynchronous code blocks with limited scope and completion handlers difficult to read and work with.  My method allows the controllers to check for data themselves whereas the typical completion handler way means the controllers have to wait to be notified which I don’t like.  Thanks

Comment: But it is still asynchronous. You don't know *when* the data load will complete. You are executing code, on the main queue, asynchronously, when the load does complete. You could adopt a `Notification` post/subscribe pattern and at least your view controller would be notified any time the data was downloaded, rather than the one-shot you have now. Where does you controller "check for itself"? That would be a blocking/polling pattern on the main queue, which is not desirable, and which you do not have.  What you have inside the `dispatchGroup.notify` *is essentially a completion handler*!

Comment: I just looked at your code again; you have a simple "retry" where you call `recursive` if there is an error,  But you never end the recursion. Run your app without a network connection and watch it crash.

Comment: You say that you "don't like completion handlers",  but honestly that is what you have built, just in a more complex and less robust way

Comment: The controller checks for itself with every group.notify call, it then gets the data from the model class using one of the exposed public methods.

Comment: Right, but the `group.notify` **is asynchronously executed**. If you are referring to the closure accesing the model object vs receiving the data directly as a parameter to the closure, that is a different thing. There is no problem with doing that, but again that is independent of sync/async. It really sounds like you should be using `NotificationCenter`

Comment: Yeah that’s what I’m talking about.  Ok it appears I have conflated something after all.

Comment: How is this a completion handler, and how is it more complex and less robust?  I'm running the app in a sim now with no network connection and its not crashing.  To be fair I do actually have reachability code which prevents it from even starting that method if it doesn't have connectivity. However it is possible I have an infinite loop there, I guess there is a possibility I will have a pretty serious crash if the server goes offline.  But, if the server goes offline, theres really no point in using my app.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Yeah I agree very much with your edit, it should be nonblockingoperation vs blockingoperation , that’s really not very clear

Comment: It is a completion handler in the sense that is completion handler is "a block of code that is executed, asynchronously, when the operation is complete".  That is precisely what you have.  Reachability might prevent you from initiating a connection when there is no network, but it won't help you if the server or network goes down mid-transfer.  Your app might not be functional if things are offline but it is nicer to show an error to the user that explains what is happening rather than simply having the app crash.

Comment: Yeah, ok I see what your saying